# Scaling an UIButton vertically only from the bottom

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation

I'm trying to animate the scaling of an UIButton but am having difficulties getting it to animate the way I want it to.

I have a UIButton set up with a stretchable UIImage. I want its height to scale to a certain size and give it the effect that it is 'growing'. I use the code below, but it animates the UIButton growing from top and bottom, rather than just bottom. See the code here:

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,0.5);
myButton.alpha = 0.6f;  
[UIView beginAnimations:@"myButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
myButton.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's hard to explain, basically I want the UIButton to grow from only one side (the bottom) rather than it grow by expanding both sides. Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE

I also tried changing the button's frame and that did not work either. This time, no animation was seen at all. This is my code:

```
CGRect  buttonRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 22);
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = buttonRect;

myButton.alpha = 0.6f;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"myButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
CGRect buttonRect2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 52);
myButton.frame = buttonRect2;
myButton.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any ideas why it is not animating at all? I'm assuming it has something to do with how I'm setting the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't see any animations until you call the `setFrame:` method..

```
CGRect  buttonRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 22);
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = buttonRect;

myButton.alpha = 0.6f;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"myButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
CGRect buttonRect2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 52);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"myButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
 myButton.alpha = 1.0f;
[myButton setFrame: buttonRect2];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You're right! I had actually done that but forgotten to but that in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to animate a change to the `frame` property, and increase the width and height there, rather than try to work out the complexities of a transformation based around the center point. If you really have a need for transforms on this view, you can always transparently update it once the animation has completed.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I tried that above (see edited question under UPDATE) and now it doesn't animate at all. Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: The update as shown looks correct. Is there anywhere else where you modify `myButton`? What does the code look like where you initialize it with the image?

Comment: Nothing special, I set my stretched image and change some label properties. Thanks for your help Justin, I still can't figure this out and it's becoming quite challenging! Any other ideas?

Comment: I just figured it out Justin, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question. You need to call layoutSubviews. 
See here:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 22);

myButton.alpha = 0.6f;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
[myButton layoutSubviews];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"myButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
myButton.alpha = 1.0f;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 52);
[myButton layoutSubviews];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```